# Нужно найти определённый символ в строке URL, потом удалить все символы после него  и его!

Tags: url, строки, php

```
http://shop.local/podsection?id=2&ids=6
```

Должно остаться

```
http://shop.local/podsection
```

Последовательность символов после знака `?` может быть разной длины и содержания.
Если можно, то функциями php, плиз.

Comment: @jobananas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'http://shop.local/podsection?id=2&ids=6';

$parts = parse_url($url);

echo $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
```

Comment: Зачем вы всегда усложняете решение своего вопроса? Эту простую операцию можно выполнить одной строчкой, при помощи регулярного выражения.

Comment: @МаринаВоин, где тут сложность, почему эту задачу надо решать через регулярку и зачем идти через контринтуитивное решение вопроса?

Comment: @Etki, а где Вы здесь видите противоречие здравому смыслу? По моему Ваш способ решения вопроса, как раз и является контринтуитивным решением. 

А что касается разницы Вашего кода и моего(регулярка), то отличие в объеме кода. Возможно для Вас это не важный критерий и в ходе разработки Вы на него не акцентируете внимание. Но когда работаешь над крупными проектами и пишешь лаконичный код, то дальнейшая поддержка/доработка кода упрощается.

Comment: > а где Вы здесь видите противоречие здравому смыслу?

Не противоречие, а контринтуитивное решение. Когда мы работаем с регуляркой, мы работаем со строкой. Когда мы работаем с урлом, мы работаем с особой строкой, которая а) подчиняется своим правилам и б) должна предполагать малозатратное расширение функционала. Если это регулярка, то у нас будет просто метод работы со строкой ("распили здесь"), который не расширить.

> По моему Ваш способ решения вопроса, как раз и является контринтуитивным решением.

я там и написал, что это однострочники и правильный - тот, под которомы мы комментарии пише

Comment: @Etki, доказывать Вам как правильно и как лучше делать - не вижу смысла. Пусть каждый останется при своём мнении. Думаю спор стоит закрыть.

Answer (score 2):

**Однострочник**

```
$strippedUrl = reset(explode('?', $url));
```

**Ущербный однострочник**

```
$strippedUrl = substr($url, 0, (($pos = strpos($url, "?")) !== false) ? $pos : strlen($url));
```

**Правильный подход**

Описан в ответе выше. Его кардинальное отличие в том, что мы работаем с URL, как с URL. Это не дает конкретных преимуществ, но придает приложению большую конкретику и ее поведение становится более ожидаемым.

Comment: Мне нужно подключать файл тпл при условии совпадения URL,
для проверки мне нужно было его очистить до знака вопроса:

    <?php if ($url = $this->url->getThisURL() == "shop.local/podsection") { ?>// функция выберает текущий URL 
    <?php include "krohi.tpl"; ?>
    <?php } ?>

В текущий URL может попадать и $url другой страницы, но если будет совпадения до знака вопроса, то нужно подключать тпл файл! В $url должен попасть очищеный вариант!

Comment: Для чего очищать? - потому что при сортировке, переключении постраничной навигации, поиске и т.д. он сильно меняется, там добавляю гет параметры и т.д. Вот потому нужно отрезать все гет параметры для сравнения, так как мне они мешают в данной задаче.

Comment: @jobananas, вам не нужно оперировать на уровне url. У вас есть конкретный кусок кода, который выполняется (контроллер) и какие-то параметры, с которыми он запущен. Соответственно вам нужно не урлы сравнивать, а текущий контроллер и его параметры.

Если же делать на уровне урлом, то сделайте как выше посоветовали и закешируйте в какую-нибудь переменную, потом просто сравнивайте и всё. А вот это вот:

     if ($url = $this->url->getThisURL() == "shop.local/podsection")

присвоит `$url` значение `true` или `false`.

Comment: 
 public function getThisURL() {
  $uri = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 1);
  return $this->config->address.$uri;
 }

В переменной храню насзвание хоста $this->config->address = shop.local;

Comment: причом здесь контроллер?

Comment: cпасибо большое, 1 ответ с pars_url(); - то, что нужно, респект автору ответа дал!

Comment: @jobananas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: > причом здесь контроллер?

При том, что необходимо соблюдать паттерны.

[Пример контроллера с роутингом по урлу](http://pastebin.com/rGiPHs7W)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/\?.*/", "", "http://shop.local/podsection?id=2&ids=6")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (preg_match("/.*?\?/",$this->url->getThisURL(),$url) { ?>// функция выбирает текущий URL 
<?php include "krohi.tpl"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Типа так? Если бы вы объяснили поконкретнее, то я мог бы дать вам и ответ поконкретнее. В текущем коде если найдена ссылка, что помещена в getThisURL, то в $url[0] будет помещена эта ссылка, и произойдёт инклуд некой крохи.tpl.